# Unknown keyword: content_type in active storage 5.2.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

If you update rails to 5.2.1.1 to avoid a potential bug in active storage (info released around 27. November 2018) then be advised that this causes a bug when uploading files to Amazon S3.

`ArgumentError: unknown keyword: content_type`

Can be fixed by upgrading rails in your gemfile to

```
gem 'rails', '5.2.2.rc1'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade to

```
gem 'rails', '5.2.2.rc1'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is now fixed with rails 5.2.2 which was released on Dec 4, 2018, see [changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v5.2.2):

> Active Storage
>
> Fix ArgumentError when uploading to amazon s3

So in your Gemfile, either set `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'` and run `bundle update rails`

or set `gem 'rails', '5.2.2` and run `bundle install rails`